# Edit formula, or convert expanded version into compact notation

Tags: r, formula, lme4

I'm writing a function in R to simplify random effects structures for (generalized) linear mixed effects models that fail to converge (using the `lme4` library). I've managed to extract the formula from the model, identify the random effect associated with the least variance, and remove it from the formula. Then, I can join everything back together and use `eval(parse(text=formula.string))` to get a formula object to return.

While the formula should work, it's not the most compact notation. For instance, suppose I fit the original model with the following formula:

```
y ~ x * z + (1 + x * z || group1) + (1 + x * z || group2)
```

Then I am able to find that the random effect associated with the least variance is, say, the main effect of `z` for `group2`. I successfully construct a new formula that removes only this effect, but then I end up with the following representation (luckily, the dependent variable and fixed effects can be extracted without expansion using `lme4`'s `nobars()`):

```
y ~ x * z + 
    (1 | group1) + (0 + x | group1) + (0 + z | group1) + (0 + x:z | group1) +
    (1 | group2) + (0 + x | group2) + (0 + x:z | group2)
```

This will work, but it's not quite as nice when displaying logging messages regarding what was changed as the ideally more compact notation:

```
y ~ x * z + (1 + x * z || group1) + (1 + x + x:z || group2)
```

Is there an easy way to go from the former (either as a formula object or as a string) to the latter without rolling my own function to do it? I could try, but given the high chance I'd make some error somewhere it'd probably not be worth it given that the verbose formula should still work correctly.

Edit:
In response to Roland's comment, here's how I'm identifying the random effect associated with the least variance and removing it; I'd be happy if there's a better way to do this, too!

```
# in context, we only call this if the model has failed to converge
# or if "boundary (singular) fit" occurs,
# based on an any(grepl()) of model@optinfo$conv$lme4$messages
simplify.lmem.formula <- function(model) {
    formula <- formula(model)

    fixed.effects <- deparse(nobars(formula))
    random.effects <- sapply(findbars(formula), deparse)
    
    sds <- as.data.frame(VarCorr(model))
    sds <- sds[order(sds$vcov),]
    least.variance.group <- gsub('\\.[1-9]*$', '', sds[1, 'grp'])
    least.variance.effect <- gsub('\\(Intercept\\)', '1', sds[1,'var1'])
    
    to.remove <- paste0(least.variance.effect, ' \\| ', least.variance.group)
    
    # check to make sure we remove 1 and only 1 effect
    pre.removal.length <- length(random.effects)
    random.effects <- random.effects[!grepl(paste0('(^| )', to.remove, '$'), random.effects)]
    post.removal.length <- length(random.effects)
    if (post.removal.length != pre.removal.length - 1) {
        cat('Error: >1 random effect removed!\n')
        return ()
    }
    
    new.formula.str <- paste0(
                         fixed.effects,
                         ' + (',
                         paste0(random.effects, collapse = ') + ('),
                         ')'
                       )
     # changed from eval(parse(text=new.formula.str))
     # based on Roland's comment
     new.formula <- as.formula(new.formula.str)
}
```

Comment: Don't use `eval(parse(text=formula.string))`, use `as.formula` if you cannot do it without text processing. I think you should show how you "identify the random effect associated with the least variance, and remove it from the formula".

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really have time to look into this right now. But you should take care with the formula's environment. You probably want something like `as.formula(new.formula.str, env = environment(formula))`. I dislike the use of text processing here. It is possible to modify formulas directly. Formulas are call objects, which means you can modify them just like a call.

Comment: I didn't realize that—I'll have to look into how to do that. If you do happen to have time at some point, I'd be interested if you (or anyone else) could give me a point in the right direction about how to do it the right way. I'm also unhappy with using text processing, but I wasn't sure how else to go about it.

Comment: Looking into this, it looks like the `update.formula` function might be the ticket, once the formula is converted into the expanded notation (since otherwise you have to remove the entire random effect and add it back, which seems error-prone). However, the trick then becomes getting the actual formula object for the random effect to be removed; I'm not sure how to extract that cleanly from the `VarCorr.merMod` function, since it just seems like it returns group and effect names (e.g., `group1` and `x:z`, in separate columns), as opposed to the actual effect (e.g., `(0 + x:z | group1)`).

Answer (score 0):

Try `gsub`.

```
fo <- y ~ x * z + (1 + x * z || group1) + (1 + x * z || group2) 

as.formula(paste(gsub('z || group2', 'x:z || group2', fo, fixed=TRUE)[c(2, 1, 3)], collapse=' '))
# y ~ x * z + (1 + x * z || group1) + (1 + x * x:z || group2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this will necessarily work straightforwardly for more complex designs (suppose I have `(1 + x * z * w || group1)`, in which case I want `(1 + x * w + x:z + z:w + x:z:w || group1)` if the main effect of `z` in `group1` is still the culprit, or if the culprit was instead the main effect of `x` in `group1`).